# Update a field in Word 2013 using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a word document where I use fields (with Document properties) in the text, in the Footers but I also created an Word Art object with the Title-field in it.

I can Update the fields in the document using:

```
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
```

For the Footers I use the PrintPreview

```
ActiveDocument.PrintPreview
ActiveDocument.ClosePrintPreview
```

But none of those updates my Field in the Word Art Object.

How can I update this?

Answer (score 0):

A wordart object is a shape, is it really the case, that a word art object can *contain* a field instead of just overlaying? Can you put out some more information/ did you double check if the field may have been updated but the content stays the same?

Comment: > is it really the case, that a word art object can contain a field instead of just overlaying?

Yes you can really use A field, I inserted a field in the Object and can manually update it by right clicking the field and Hit "Update Field" I changed the contents of the field and after updating my Shape changes also.

< I also did a test adding more then one Field to a Word Art Object, I can update the different fields the same way, right click a field and update the field. I can also select all contents of the shape and update using F9

Answer (score 0):

I have found a suitable work arround in Word for my problem.

It is not realy neccesary to use Word Art, I can use the same with "Text Effects and Typography"

I am still curious if there is a real solotion for this, but for now it works dor me